# Disabling 'hover' in Windows 8 Simulator in Touch mode

Tags: windows, touch

I'm using the Windows 8 Simulator to do some testing of my website in IE10 using touch. However, when I select the single point (basic) touch mode (or any touch mode, for that matter), I find that Windows (and IE) still generate hover events. What I really want to do is test as if I was on a purely touch system with no support for hover.

Is it possible to adjust the Simulator so that it only responds to taps and related events, and not hover?